# Octave - remove occurrences of an element in a cell array

Tags: arrays, cell, octave

In Octave, I have this cell array:
`y = { 'hello' 'world' 'a' 'world' 'g' 'I' 'w' 'hi'};`

I need to be able to remove the duplicates of an element. So for example I want to remove the duplicates of `'world'`, this should be the output:

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] = hello
  [1,2] = a
  [1,3] = g
  [1,4] = I
  [1,5] = w
  [1,6] = hi
}
```

Aside from the usual loop until n times, is there a function in Octave that does this?

I've been looking for ways to do this but found nothing. From what I've seen, `unique` does not do this as it removes all duplicates.

Comment: You removed *all* occurrences of `world` is that really what you wanted?

Comment: @CH123: Is the order of the result important? And do you want to remove multiple duplicates? For example `y={"foo", "hello", "bar", "baz","hello", "world", "foo"}` should remove hello and foo?

Comment: @Suever, yes I want to remove every instances of `world`.

@Andy, the order is not important (so it's okay if it returns an array with an ascending order like `unique` does). And multiple duplicates is also fine, but not at all necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove *all* occurrences of a string from a cell array like you have shown in your example, you can simply use `strcmp`.

```
x = y(~strcmp(y, 'world'));

%// {
%//     [1,1] = hello
%//     [1,2] = a
%//     [1,3] = g
%//     [1,4] = I
%//     [1,5] = w
%//     [1,6] = hi
%// }
```

And this can easily be adapted if you want to remove multiple pairs of duplicates at once you can use `ismember`.

```
y = {'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'};
x = y(~ismember(y, {'a', 'b'});
```

If you instead want to remove all but the first occurrence of a string, you could do something like the following.

```
toremove = find(strcmp(y, 'world'));
x = y;
x(toremove(2:end)) = [];

%// x = 
%// {
%//     [1,1] = hello
%//     [1,2] = world
%//     [1,3] = a
%//     [1,4] = g
%//     [1,5] = I
%//     [1,6] = w
%//     [1,7] = hi
%// }
```

Comment: Oh. I did not know that `strcmp` can do it. This is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Just a question, what is `~` for in `x = y(~strcmp(y, 'world'));`?

Comment: @CH123 Because you want to keep all values that *aren't* that string. The `~` negates the logical array that `strcmp` returns.

Comment: In octave you may use the `!` negation instead of `~`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically remove items with occur more than once use this:

```
y = { 'hello' 'world' 'a' 'world' 'g' 'I' 'w' 'hi'};
[Y, ~, J] = unique (y);
cnt = accumarray (J(:), 1);
Y(cnt == 1)

ans = 
{
  [1,1] = I
  [1,2] = a
  [1,3] = g
  [1,4] = hello
  [1,5] = hi
  [1,6] = w
}
```

cnt counts the occurrence of each string so Y(cnt == 1) only includes strings which occure exactly once.